# Different log level for different Karaf Bundles

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

In `Karaf 3.0.5` running under `Servicemix 6.1.0` my `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` looks like below:-

```
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, async, osgi:*
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer

# To avoid flooding the log when using DEBUG level on an ssh connection and doing log:tail
log4j.logger.org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelSession = INFO

# CONSOLE appender not used by default
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %X | %m%n

# File appender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %X | %m%n
log4j.appender.out.file=/tmp/servicemix.log
log4j.appender.out.append=true
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=1024MB
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=10

# Sift appender
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=bundle.name
log4j.appender.sift.default=servicemix
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=/tmp/$\\{bundle.name\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true

# Async appender
log4j.appender.async=org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender
log4j.appender.async.appenders=out
```

Now this logger config is dumping Karaf's debug log as well whereas my intention is to `DEBUG` only a specific bundle.

Can some one let me know if it is possible to set different log levels for different bundles? What I am trying to ask is let's say I have two bundles `bundle1` and `bundle2`. I want `bundle1` log level to be `DEBUG` and `bundle2` log level to `ERROR`. Is this possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in karaf [mailing-list](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Different-log-level-for-different-Karaf-Bundles-td4047003.html) since I was using different logger for different bundle. So just setting the log level (as shown below) for bundle level logger in `org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` solved it for me.

```
log4j.logger.com.j1.bundle1 = DEBUG
```

One more solution was suggested in the above mentioned thread. I did not try it but just quoting it below:-

> You can do this by using MDC combined with filters (I implemented that
>   in Pax logging a few years back).
>
> E g if you use this root logger:
>
> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, info, error, bundle, context, osgi:*
>
> And you define the "bundle" log as follows:
>
> log4j.appender.bundle=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
>   log4j.appender.bundle.key=bundle.name
>   log4j.appender.bundle.default=karaf
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.MaxFileSize=1MB
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.MaxBackupIndex=2
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} |
>   %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %m%n
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.file=${logdir}/bundles/$\{bundle.name\}.log
>   log4j.appender.bundle.appender.append=true
>   log4j.appender.bundle.threshold=INFO
>
> You will end up with a separate log file per bundle (named with the
>   bundle's name). I use a custom variable (${logdir}) to specify where
>   to create the log file but you can do as you wish. In this case these
>   log files will be at INFO level.
>
> Sometimes I want TRACE logging on a specific bundle. I can then do as
>   follows:
>
> log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout, info, error, bundle, context, osgi:*,
>   bundle_trace
>
> log4j.appender.bundle_trace=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.key=bundle.name
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.default=karaf
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.MaxFileSize=10MB
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.MaxBackupIndex=2
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}
>   | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %-32.32C %4L | %m%n
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.file=${logdir}/bundles/trace/$\{bundle.name\}.log
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.appender.append=true
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.threshold=TRACE
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.filter.a=org.apache.log4j.filter.MDCMatchFilter
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.filter.a.exactMatch=false
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.filter.a.keyToMatch=bundle.name
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.filter.a.valueToMatch=org.apache.aries.blueprint.core
>   log4j.appender.bundle_trace.filter.z=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
>
> In the above example I create a separate TRACE log for the bundle with
>   the name "org.apache.aries.blueprint.core".
>
> It is also possible to configure custom logging for a particular camel
>   context which we do in our integration platform based on Karaf and
>   Camel.
>   Also one thing to note DenyAllFilter should be the last filer in the above config.